# How can I make Matlab's editor smart indent always on while writing code?

Tags: matlab, editor, auto-indent

While working with Matlab I'm using very often the combination of  Ctrl+A (select all) followed by Ctrl+I (smart indent). Can I make Matlab's editor smart indent option working automatically, while I type code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`File > Preferences > Editor/Debugger > Language > Apply smart indenting while typing`